# Call Transfer, do not disconnect unless connected

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I have elastix PBX, and when I transfer a call to other extension, I got "Redirect Success" even if the extension I transferred the call to not answered or busy.

The case Is:

A is on call with B.
B transferred the call to C.
B got "Redirect Success" even if C is not answered the call, or C is busy.
And the call is disconnected from B.

What I need is:
B still connected with A unless C answered the call.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer, the PBX respond "Redirect Success", whenever the destination extension is found, regardless of the status, otherwise it will respond "Redirect Failure"